# How to select multiple individual cells on Google Sheets on my Android mobile phone?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-named-ranges

How to select multiple individual cells on Google Sheets on my Android mobile phone?

Example:
[image]

On Windows it is possible by using the CTRL button + left mouse button click, but I did not find any solution on Google Sheets for Android.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with what you are actually seeking to achieve. Please also explain in your question why the answer provided specifically does not address your question as it stands.

Comment: Well your answer was completely wrong. Not even related to the question.

Comment: If this question is about using the Google Sheets Android app then is off-topic in this site; try [android.se]. If this question is about using Google Sheets in a web browser please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as well the name and version of the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows it is possible by using the CTRL button + left mouse button
> click, but I did not find any solution on Google Sheets for Android.

The shortcuts won't work on Android.

Comment: Your answer still shows how to select cell range. See image in my edited OP.

Comment: OK your question is clearer now. I've removed part of my answer but left the part to say it's not possible.

Comment: Well, AFAIK this is not true. Shortcuts are working on Android, if specific virtual keyboard is used, which has CTRL button. But the question was about the Google Sheets user interface, if it supports selecting multiple individual cells.

Comment: "But the question was about the Google Sheets user interface, if it supports selecting multiple individual cells" but as @Ruben has already indicated, your question is off-topic here and should be addressed on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) so is academic here.